# Trying to do getElementById on a <li> which I created within a function, returns null

Tags: javascript

I am creating a Google Maps info window, in which I want to place a clickable text to set a start and end point.

So, I want to add listeners to the text, which I have created within the initialisation of the window.

In the below code, the `showInfoWindow(marker)` successfully shows appears and the start/end text is there.

However, if that is the only info window present, I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`.

If I debug, I *can't* get the element after the `infoWindow.open(map, marker);` (at which point the window isn't actually visible),
but I *can* once the window has appeared (it goes through a lot of google's own native code before this happens)

I even tried adding the listeners after the line which calls `showInfoWindow(marker)` but it still doesn't work.

```
function showInfoWindow(marker) {


     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: (marker.title 
      + '<br><img id="thumbnail" src = "img/' 
      + marker.title.toLowerCase() 
      + '.jpg"><br>'
      + '<ul>'
      + '<li id="infoWindowStart">Start from here</li>'
      + '<li id="infoWindowEnd">End here</li>'
      + '</ul>'
      )

  });

      infoWindow.open(map, marker);

   // then try to add a listener to the newly-created "infoWindowStart"
       document.getElementById("infoWindowStart").addEventListener("click",function(){
  console.log("We're going from here")
 });


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`domready` event is fired when the info window is attached to DOM.
So you can use the following code.

```
infoWindow.addListener("domready", function() {
  var infoWindowDom = document.getElementById("infoWindowStart");
  console.log(infoWindowDom); // check if it's loaded correctly
  infoWindowDom.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("We're going from here")
  });
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I can see `domready` saving me a lot of headaches in the future